# How to manage multiple distributed build clusters

Tags: jenkins, build, distributed-system

I have multiple heavy applications, which are dependant from each other.

- Application A, ip 10.0.0.1
- Application B, ip 10.0.0.2

The applications are too fat, to be executed on the same machine, 
so I end up in having 2 machines, building, executing, testing those applications.

For applications to speak with each other - they have their ips in their configs.

Now in order to run the tests after each  commit, I wish to be able to start multiple pairs of machines, running applications A, B.

**Question:** 
Is there some tooling to manage multiple dependent pairs of machines in Jenkins? 
 I think about seeing the dependent pairs of machines somewhere in Jenkins, their IPs. Starting the machines in pairs. For exchanging the configurations and updating the IPs in such a pairs I probably can take 
"puppet" or "chef".

Comment: Jenkins is for CI first place (building, testing, deployment), not about slave nodes management. Though you may be able to achieve what you want with [Jenkins Pipeline plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin) to run coupled jobs on slave nodes. That will need smart approach for job description anyway

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, by "not about slave nodes management". Slave maangement is a part of a CI tool, since Jenkins supports distributed builds? Jenkins Pipeline is about VIZUALIZATION of a build chain, NOT about pairing the nodes. So what is the point of this comment?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to run the apps on the test boxes Puppet, Chef, and Ansible are overkill. Use the fabric python module or if you like ruby mina or capistrano http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/usage/execution.html. 
The script would go

```
@hosts("x.x.x.x")    
def app1(): 
    run("startapp&")
@hosts("x.x.x.x")
def app2():
    run("startapp2&")
```

`

then have jenkins execute fab app1 app2
Configuration management tools should be used when you have a more complex infrastructure that needs to be built repeatedly and it also is a sort of documentation on the infrastructure if you made a mistake. They shouldn't be used to just run commands on different nodes. This is especially true if you're using Chef or Puppet.